# Call to undefined method Slim\\Psr7\\Response::write()

Tags: php, slim

I have just installed composer and create a project using composer create-project slim\slim-skeleton MyApi. using Slim V4. Creation was successful but I failed to run routes requiring database operations.

```php
<?php

// ...

require __DIR__ . '/../includes/DbOperations.php';

// ...

$app->post('/hello', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    $response->getBody()->write('Hello world!');
    return $response;
});

$app->post('/createuser', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    if (!haveEmptyParameters(array('uname', 'uphone', 'upassword', 'uposition', 'ucreated'), $request, $response)) {
        $request_data = $request->getParsedBody();

        $uname = $request_data['uname'];
        $uphone = $request_data['uphone'];
        $upassword = $request_data['upassword'];
        $uposition = $request_data['uposition'];
        $ucreated = $request_data['ucreated'];
        // ...
    }
});
```

`localhost:8080/hello` works fine, however `localhost:8080/createuser` fails with an error `{ "statusCode": 500, "error": { "type": "SERVER_ERROR", "description": "Call to undefined method Slim\\Psr7\\Response::write()" } }`

What may the problem be? Thank you in advance.
With Love from Gulu, Uganda, East Africa.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow community, please read this before asking: (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and please format your question with code (markdown support included) and other useful tags.

Answer (score 2):

We cannot see the full content of the `/createuser` route.

I guess you have to invoke `$response->getBody()` to write content to the response.

Example

```php
$response->getBody()->write("Hello world");

return $response;
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to help me out.

Comment: The problem is not the content of the /createuser, because it worked fine in the Slim v3. The problem seem to be in registering routes. If I placed the same code snippet (/createuser) on routes.php as in the new Slim V4 directory section. I get an error that registering 2 similar routes is not allowed. I don't seem to understand how to add routes and use in SLim V4.